# How Does Scrollview Work With Autolayout, and Why Does Setting the Bottom Vertical Space Constraint Make it Work?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to understand how UIScrollView works in an auto layout environment. So far I've tried reading the Apple documentation, Stack Overflow research, Google research, and studying Matt Neuberg's working example.

The Apple 6.1 documentation says:

> The central notion of a UIScrollView object (or, simply, a scroll
>   view) is that it is a view whose origin is adjustable over the content
>   view. It clips the content to its frame, which generally (but not
>   necessarily) coincides with that of the application’s main window. A
>   scroll view tracks the movements of fingers and adjusts the origin
>   accordingly. The view that is showing its content “through” the scroll
>   view draws that portion of itself based on the new origin, which is
>   pinned to an offset in the content view. The scroll view itself does
>   no drawing except for displaying vertical and horizontal scroll
>   indicators. The scroll view must know the size of the content view so
>   it knows when to stop scrolling; by default, it “bounces” back when
>   scrolling exceeds the bounds of the content.

Based on this, let's walk through how constraints ought to be set up.

To make it easier to discuss, lets say we have 3 views as a general case - the default main view controller view (A), its subview being a UIScrollview (B), and the UIScrollview has a single subview which is a UIView (C). Let's say we want (C) to be 1000 units tall.

So we go into the interface builder, select the view controller in the story board and on the attributes inspector tab change the size to freeform. For views (A), (B), and (C) we change the height to 1000 on the size inspector tab.

**Constraints Between (A) and Main Window**

Time to setup constraints. The documentation clearly states "(The Scrollview) clips the content to its frame, which generally (...) coincides with that of the application’s main window". In our example (A) will coincide with the application main window and no constraints are necessary for this.

**Constraints Between (A) and (B)**

Now the documentation was clear about having (B) coincide exactly with (A), so we'll set up 4 constraints between them, leading space, trailing space, top space, and bottom space to superview all with a constant of 0.

**Constraints Between (B) and (C)**

The documentation is not so straight forward here. It says that (B)'s origin is adjustable over (C), so (B) should definitely be smaller than (C). Since we know the scrolling is only going to be up and down, we can constrain the left and right edged between (B) and (C) to zero, and we always want it to be in the middle so we'll add a center x alignment. We'll add 3 constraints between them, leading space and trailing space to superview with a constant of 0, and center x alignment. In order to position the view we need something for the top and bottom, and honestly I'm not sure how these constraints should be set up based on the documentation. Based on imitating Matt Neuberg's [example](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/ch20p573scrollViewAutoLayout2) I made them top space to superview with a constant of zero, and bottom space to superview with whatever constant it generates by default. This bottom space to superview constraint is special (apparently), from now on it shall be referred to as "specialConstraint".

So... what?! We started this paragraph out by saying (B) should definitely be smaller than (C), and ended it by setting up constraints to make them exactly the same size. *Question 1 - Why is this?*

**Constraints on (C) by Itself**

We know that (C) must be larger than (B) so that (B) has something to scroll over, and (C) should determine its size based on its own constraints. Easy enough, we set 1 constraint, height = 1000.

**specialConstraint**

Now we create an outlet for specialConstraint in the view controller, and in the viewDidLoad method we set self.specialConstraint.constant = 0; This means that the bottom of the content view should be pinned exactly to the bottom of the scroll view, which would give you nothing to scroll down over. But this works in Matt Neuberg's example. *Question 2 - why is this?*

**What's Really Happening When a Scrollview Scrolls**

I would think the logical thing to do would be to have the frame of the scroll view fixed, and the origin of the content view (or the content offset) move around with the scrolling and the content shows the scrollview like a window. Similar to viewing a paper through a hole in a wall by sliding the paper around.

However, based on my reading the scrollview's frame is actually doing the moving, like a magnifying glass over a fixed page.

*Question 3 - Can someone please explain what's happening when a scrollview scrolls, which object's frame origin is actually changing, and why is it done this way?*

*Question 4 - Can anyone explain how the constraints should be set between (A), (B), and (C) in plain English?*

Comment: Just two notes:

"We'll add 3 constraints between them [B and C], leading space and trailing space to superview with a constant of 0, and center x alignment."

center x alignment is redundant, since you're already setting the leading and trailing. Shouldn't this be center y (in order to load the view in the center of the content)?

Comment: and: "So... what?! We started this paragraph out by saying (B) should definitely be smaller than (C), and ended it by setting up constraints to make them exactly the same size." As you said yourself, the specialConstraint was set to "whatever constant it generates by default", so you're not necessarily making them the same size, I think. And you have to distinguish between the size of the scrollView (total content area) and the size of the *bounds* (not the correct term, but...)

Answer (score 0):

### Working example

Hi. At first, here is working code scroll view example writed couple of days ago.

```
[self addSubview:scrollView];

id views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView);
[self addConstraints:PVVFL(@"H:|[scrollView]|").withViews(views).asArray];
[self addConstraints:PVVFL(@"V:|[scrollView]|").withViews(views).asArray];
```

Constraints writed in code and with help of [Parus](https://github.com/DAlOG/Parus) lib.

As you can mention, scroll view is tied to it's superview. In another words, it fill it completely.

Couple of lines earlier i setup an `scrollView` tree.

```
id views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(photoView, storeNameLabel, selectStoreButton, tagsLabel, tagsContainer, editTagsButton, commentView, sendButton, cancelButton);
[scrollView addConstraints:PVVFL(@"V:|-15-[photoView(150)]").withViews(views).asArray];
[scrollView addConstraints:PVVFL(@"|-15-[photoView]-15-|").withViews(views).asArray];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVCenterXOf(photoView).equalTo.centerXOf(scrollView).asConstraint];

[scrollView addConstraint:PVTopOf(storeNameLabel).equalTo.bottomOf(photoView).plus(20).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraints:
 PVVFL(@"|-15-[storeNameLabel]-(>=15)-[selectStoreButton]-15-|")
 .alignAllBaseline.withViews(views).asArray];
[selectStoreButton setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                                                   forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];

[scrollView addConstraints:
 PVVFL(@"V:[storeNameLabel]-15-[tagsLabel][tagsContainer]").alignAllLeft.withViews(views).asArray];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVRightOf(tagsContainer).equalTo.rightOf(selectStoreButton).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVTopOf(editTagsButton).equalTo.bottomOf(tagsContainer).plus(10).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVWidthOf(editTagsButton).equalTo.widthOf(tagsContainer).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVLeftOf(editTagsButton).equalTo.leftOf(tagsContainer).asConstraint];

[scrollView addConstraint:PVTopOf(commentView).equalTo.bottomOf(editTagsButton).plus(10).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVWidthOf(commentView).equalTo.widthOf(editTagsButton).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVLeftOf(commentView).equalTo.leftOf(editTagsButton).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVHeightOf(commentView).moreThan.constant(100).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVLeftOf(cancelButton).equalTo.leftOf(commentView).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraints:PVVFL(@"[cancelButton]-(>=15)-[sendButton(==cancelButton)]").alignAllBaseline.withViews(views).asArray];
[scrollView addConstraint:PVRightOf(sendButton).equalTo.rightOf(commentView).asConstraint];
[scrollView addConstraints:PVVFL(@"V:[commentView]-10-[cancelButton]-10-|").withViews(views).asArray];
```

How you can see, this is pretty complicated layout. 
But key points of it: Internal views have fixed heights, provided by theirs intrinsic content sizes. Combined all together they tried to increase height of `scrollView`.
**But `scrollView` height is fixed by `self.view`**!!! Constraint solver must generate error. But,

### Theory

Apple has special [Tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) for this case. And there is some interesting moment:

> To make this work with Auto Layout, the top, left, bottom, and right edges within a scroll view now mean the **edges of its content view**.

Also this note provide some examples of different approaches when working with scroll views and auto-layouts.

Now i will try to answer your questions.

### Answers

> *Question 1 - Why is this?*

As you can read above, this is because auto-layout for scroll view setup content view sizes and not frame sizes.

> *Question 2 - why is this?*

Again, thing is in content size. *Special constraint* approach looks like hack over interface builder. At xib you have normal size view, and after nib-file instantiating you just back things to normal, fixing this constraint to 0, which mean that **content size** of scroll view will be equal to C view.

> *Question 3 - Can someone please explain what's happening when a scrollview scrolls, which object's frame origin is actually changing, and why is it done this way?*

Great explanation of this process you can find at this article: [Understanding Scroll Views](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/scroll-view.html), but short answer is: *UIScroll view perform scrolling by changing `self.bounds.origin` point.*

> *Question 4 - Can anyone explain how the constraints should be set between (A), (B), and (C) in plain English?*

You should set constraints inside the scroll view by fixing all edges to internal view. In another words, all edges of scroll view must be fixed twice: By internal views and by superview.

If answer on this question are not clear yet, you can read this answer from very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I found a lot of examples how to do it but not one explaining how to set the contensize at Runtime. So with a button.

Actually it all boils down to having a relation between your scrollviews content and the scrollView.

Now you can make a scrollview scroll and resize without code just in storyboard. Only you have to do it right.

To adjust the contensize with a button (at runtime) you need to adjust the constraints of your content.

This is difficult to understand. I have put the code on github http://goo.gl/qrXANp and you can find video about it here ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oCWxHLBQ-A

Answer (score 0):

> Basic trick to solve this mystery issue is .. Embedded another view
>   inside scrollview and set constraints like below
>
> UIView --> UIScrollView -->ContentView

and you can keep on add subview to contentView at runtime and uiscrollview content size will increase automatically

```
   self.ContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.ContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.scrollview sizeToFit];

    [self.scrollview addSubview:self.ContentView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollview];

    NSMutableDictionary *views = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [views setValue:self.ContentView forKey:@"ContentView"];
    [views setValue:self.scrollview forKey:@"scrollview"];
    [views setValue:self.view forKey:@"mainView"];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[scrollview]-0-|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[scrollview]-0-|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views]];

    [self.scrollview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[ContentView]|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views]];

    [self.scrollview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[ContentView]|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[ContentView(==mainView)]"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:views]];

    self.view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```